# A general term of classes and structs?

Tags: c++

I understand that structs are very similar to classes, only member access and inheritance defaults to public. Conventionally, they're used as POD types, but, again, that's just a convention.

Despite the small differences (and the differences in the convention of using them), it's clear that classes and structs are both just slightly different interpretations of *something*, where that *something* defines the behavior of a set of objects. What's that *something*?

I know that's how classes are usually defined, but structs fit the definition too, and, at least in C++, structs mean something slightly different than a class. Or would you simply distinguish between a class (as a concept) and C++ classes (which, along with C++ structs, would be a specific implementation / approach to the class concept)?

Comment: Classes. In the C++ world, at least, a struct is just a degenerate case of a class.

Comment: A struct is a class whose default visibility is `public`.

Comment: So, if someone showed me a struct and asked me if it defined a class, I should tell them "yes"? It seems like that'd just be more likely to confuse them about the visibility differences with a class and struct.

Comment: @KevinMills: The visibility differences should be well understood by any C++ programmer. In one way `struct` is a carryover from `C`, but I believe Bjarne didn't want to reuse the `struct` keyword as people would think of the C struct, so he chose a new keyword. However, a `struct` **is** a class in C++, plain and simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Types declared using `class` and `struct` are collectively referred to as "non-union classes" by the C++ standard. As for their common behaviour... well, you obviously know what that is already.